# basic sql query and how to use it in an inventory file for playbook for list / elements=dictionary

Tags: ansible-2.x

This is based on a simple sql query.

```
select ip_address from servers where hostname like "web%";
```

This will return a set of tuples that get set in a variable of some kind.

server1: 1.1.1.1

server2: 2.2.2.2

vs

server1: 1.1.1.1

server2: 2.2.2.2

serverx: x.x.x.x

Now I want to use this query to either generate an inventory or run it directly in a playbook.
If I know the number of servers and it is fixed then I could just provide an id value based on the fixed number of returns.
But if I want to have the id increment for each ip_address returned, what would the playbook look like?

Known number of sql query results is 2

```
---
- hosts: all 
  tasks:
   - name: add some web servers
     when: inventory_hostname in groups["web_servers"]
       add_server_cluster:
         server_cluster: 
           cluster_ip: {{cluster_ip}}
           name: "web servers"
           servers:
             - 
               id: "1"
               ip: {{server1}}
             -
               id: "2"
               ip: {{server2}}
```

variable number of sql query results

```
---
- hosts: all 
  tasks:
   - name: add some web servers
     when: inventory_hostname in groups["web_servers"]
       add_server_cluster:
         server_cluster:
           cluster_ip: {{cluster_ip}}
           name: "web servers"
           servers:
             - 
               id: {{start at 1 and increment for each ip_address returned}}
               ip: {{start at first ip_address and continue for all returns}}
```

Aside from those two possible playbooks I have an inventory file already defined. This is for a fixed sql query that returns two servers.

```
--- 
all:
  children:
    web_servers:
      hosts:
        192.168.1.1:
          cluster_ip: 192.168.1.1
          server1: {{sql query row 0}}
          server2: {{sql query row 1}}
        192.168.2.1:
          cluster_ip: 192.168.2.1
          server1: {{sql query row 0}}
          server2: {{sql query row 1}}
```

Would the sql query be put in the hosts file or in the playbook for multiple returns? I want the sql query to return as many server ip values as contained in the query without having to hard code the number of servers in the inventory file.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ansible's dynamic inventory feature. This feature allows you to generate an inventory dynamically from an external system. You can write a custom dynamic inventory script in Python to fetch the data from the SQL database and format it into the inventory format that Ansible can understand.

Basic example of how to do this:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import json
import pymssql

def dynamic_inventory():
    conn = pymssql.connect(host='dbsever', user='username', password='password', database='inventory_db')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("select ip_address from servers where hostname like 'web%';")
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    
    inventory = {'all': {'hosts': []}, '_meta': {'hostvars': {}}}
    for i, row in enumerate(rows, start=1):
        host = {'id': str(i), 'ip': row[0]}
        inventory['all']['hosts'].append(host)
        inventory['_meta']['hostvars'][host] = host
    print(json.dumps(inventory))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    dynamic_inventory()
```

The `dynamic_inventory` function connects to the SQL database, executes the SQL query to get the IP addresses of the servers, and generates the inventory in the format that Ansible expects. It then prints the inventory in JSON format, which is what Ansible expects from a dynamic inventory script.

To use this script in a playbook, you can pass it to the `-i` option of the `ansible-playbook` command:

```
ansible-playbook -i dynamic_inventory.py playbook.yml
```

In the playbook, you can access the IP addresses and IDs of the servers using the `hostvars` variable:

```
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: add some web servers
      add_server_cluster:
        server_cluster: 
          name: "web servers"
          servers:
            - 
              id: "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname].id }}"
              ip: "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname].ip }}"
```

The `add_server_cluster` task uses the `hostvars` variable to access the IP address and ID of each server. The `inventory_hostname` variable contains the name of the current host in the loop.

Comment: I am getting TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict' from the line 

inventory['_meta']['hostvars'][host] = host. 

 I converted from mssql to mysql. the connection works and the query works.

Answer (score 0):

In direct response to your question of the query you have in mind,

I've made a Python plugin that does exactly this, so you can just specify your database details and query, take note of the requirements in the `README` - mainly two things:

- Python's pymysql package
- The inventory (yml) filename must end with mysql.yml/yaml

https://github.com/j-oss2023/mysql-dynamic-inventory

Copy the `mysql-dynamic-inventory.py` file to your inventory plugins dir...

The inventory plugin path can be found by running the command:

`ansible-config dump | grep INVENTORY_PLUGIN`

Example output:

```
DEFAULT_INVENTORY_PLUGIN_PATH(/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg) = ['/etc/ansible/plugins/inventory']
```

As you can see from the Example output above, my inventory plugin path is `/etc/ansible/plugins/inventory` - so copy the file into that directory, or like i have (for organization), a sub directory called `mysql-dynamic-inventory`

So in the example case, the file should live at:

`/etc/ansible/plugins/inventory/mysql-dynamic-inventory/mysql-dynamic-inventory.py`

Then in your inventory YAML file, specify the plugin, db connections details, and query... as so.

`web-servers-mysql.yml`:

```
#   Required columns: 
#   'inventory_group', 'inventory_hostname'
#
#   TLDR:
#   Besides the required columns, each column will be assigned 
#   as an ansible hostvar dynamically.

plugin: mysql-dynamic-inventory
db_host: mysql_server
db_user: mysql_user
db_pass: mysql_pass
db_name: mysql_database
db_query: |
  SELECT ip_address as ansible_host, hostname as inventory_hostname, 'web_servers' as inventory_group from servers where hostname like "web%";
```

Then verify the inventory with:

`ansible-inventory -i web-servers-mysql.yml --graph`

or

`ansible-inventory -i web-servers-mysql.yml --list`

Hope that helps!

Feel free to open an issue in the GitHub repo if you find a problem with the plugin :)